# Distribution of $S_k/\sqrt{kT_k}$ where $S_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^kX_i$ and $T_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^kX_i^2$ for i.i.d. standard normal $(X_i)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Given $X_i\sim N(0,1)$, $X_i$'s are independent, define
>   $$Z=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\sqrt{k\times\sum_{i=1}^k X_i^2}}$$
>   What is the distribution of Z?

I know that $X_i^2\sim\chi^2(1)$, and $\sum_{i=1}^kX_i\sim N(0,k)$, and $\sum_{i=1}^kX_i\sim \chi^2(k)$, thus
$$Z = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{k}\times\sum_{i=1}^k(\frac{X_i}{\sigma})^2}}$$

If we know the numerator and denominator are independent, then $Z$ has a student-t distribution with degree of freedom $k$.

My question is how to show independence if it is true? If they are dependent, then what distribution $Z$ has?

Comment: Let's see if it's true for $n=1$... i.e. is $X$ independent from $X^2$? Obviously not. The usual independence deployed to derive the $T$ test is between $\sum X_i$ and $\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2.$

Comment: Are you asking about the limit in distribution when $k\to\infty$? 'Cause that one is easy...

Comment: Write down the expression for the $T$ statistic, where the numerator and denominator are independent. Then you should be able to express $T$ in terms of $Z$, or vice versa. Basically, this involves expressing $\sum X_i^2$ in terms of $\sum (X_i-\bar X)^2$ and $\bar X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Perhaps it will be helpful to do it for $k=2$ (since in the case $k=1$, we just have $Z=1$).

We can think geometrically and let $$ Y_i = \frac{X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k X_j^2}}.$$ Then $\vec Y = (Y_1,Y_2)$ is just a point on the unit circle, and in fact by symmetry it must be uniformly distributed on the unit circle.

Now we can compute $$P(Z\le z) = P(Y_1+Y_2 \le \sqrt{2}z)$$ by sketching the region of the plane we're interested in and figuring out what fraction of the unit circle lives in that region. This gives $$ P(Z\le z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin(z).$$

Now the general case is the same idea in more dimensions. It's just finding the fraction of a hypersphere's area that is below a hyperplane. The PDF has a tidy closed form.